# SwiftUI: Determine flow in a complex view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm bulding a workout app with SwiftUI, and want to know the best way to control the following case.

The workout view contains a video of the exericse, following multiple rows of all the exercises the user must do.

[VIDEO]
[EXERCISE 1]
[EXERCISE 2]
[EXERCISE 3]

Each [EXERCISE 1] is an own view, contaiting a progress bar, letting the user know which exercise is currently active and how much time is left.

When the user enter the screen, the first exercise, [EXERCISE 1] should become active, and the progress bar should start animating. When the time is up, the next exercise should become active until all exericses has been completed.

In UIKit, this would be very easy. I would just call a "start()" method for the first exericse, and then have a callback, "exericsesDidFinish", and could then start the next exercise.

I tried a similar setup with SwiftUI, but it seems there's should be a more SwiftUI way to do this?

How would I accomplish this with SwiftUI?

Answer (score 1):

If I implemented it, I would create a view as a base view for the four views in order to make the transition you want. the base view would have a timer to do the time based task like the following.

```
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
```

The interval could be set properly based on the progress resolution.
And then, I would subscribe the timer with `onReceive` modifier with a handler where some transition logic is placed in.

And I would also use `transition` modifier to apply any animation effect to the transition.

I will briefly show you a pseudo code for your information.

```
struct BaseView: View {

  @State private var step: STEP = .first
  let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        if step == .first {
          FirstStepView()
            .transition(.opacity)
        } else if step == .second {
          SecondStepView()
            .transition(.opacity)
        }
    }
    .overlay(progressBar)
    .onReceive(timer) { tick in
        ....
        `step` can be changed in proper condition
    }
  }

  var progressBar: some View {
     ... implement the progress bar ...
  }
}
```